# Why can't I place Rectangle2D in BorderLayout freely?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I need help. I'm trying to experiment with Java GUI, and trying to draw up a Mancala Game board. Below is the code for my Mancala Board that I have so far, however, when I change the bold part to CENTER, it works just fine. How come it doesn't work when I use LINE_START or LINE_END?

The View is called in main via the following statement:

```
BoardView board = new BoardView();
```

Below is the BoardView Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BoardView extends JFrame{
    public BoardView(){
        setTitle("Mancala Game");
        setSize(550, 450);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        drawBoardPanel board = new drawBoardPanel();
        **add(board, BorderLayout.LINE_START);**


        JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
        footer.add(newGame);
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        footer.add(quit);
        add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
}

public class drawBoardPanel extends JPanel{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        double p1x = 25;
        double p1y = 25;
        double height = 300;
        double width = 50;
        double arcw = 10;
        double arch = 10;

        g2.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(p1x, p1y, width, height, arcw, arch));
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, when I change the bold part to CENTER, it works just fine. How come it doesn't work when I use LINE_START or LINE_END?

When you use CENTER, the components gets all the extra space available in the frame.

When you use LINE_START or LINE_END, the preferred size of the component is used to reserve space for the component.

You are doing custom painting and your component has a size of (0, 0), so there is nothing to paint.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` of your component to give the component a size that the layout manager can use:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(325, 75);
}
```